# Grails IReport Jasper returns blank page

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport

I have this problem having to display my jasper report on my grails application.
On the application I've installed the jasper plugin using the command: `grails> install-plugin jasper`
I have created `sample.jrxml` having this context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="student" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.2100000000000002"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="0" width="212" height="37"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Portal Student List]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="26"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="98" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="238" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Copyright]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

And I am calling the report either using the Jasper Tag `<g:jasperReport jasper="student" format="PDF"/>` or creating a new closure that would display the .pdf file directly to the browser using this code:

```
def report() {
        def reportDef = new JasperReportDef(folder: 'reports', name:'student.jrxml', fileFormat: JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT)
        reportDef.contentStream = jasperService.generateReport(reportDef)

        response.contentType = reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp
        response.characterEncoding = 'UTF-8'
        response.outputStream << reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray()
}
```

Either of the methods used returns a single blank page.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem :/

Comment: Just follow through the plugin documentation of Jasper on the Grails website.

Comment: If you mean http://grails.org/plugin/jasper then I did follow that. Can you please share the relevant BuildConfig.groovy fragments ("dependencies" and "plugins")? I am not sure I'm using all the right versions, as it didn't work out of the box by just adding "compile ':jasper:1.6.1'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have to resolve to the tutorials provided by Grails in this [link](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jasper) accompanied by the example given by Jasper itself provided [here](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-jasper/).