# Making Jasper 6.3.0 work with itextpdf-5.5.6 or Higher Version

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

I am using Jasper 6.3.0 but due to bouncy castle dependency I have to use itext-4.2.2 or higher and since itext-4.4.2 is being redirected to itextpdf-5.5.6(In maven) So I need some way to make jasper 6.3.0 work with itext-5.5.6 or higher. It is also fine if I could export the pdf using any other tool instead of itext in Jasper.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: iText `4.x.x` was never released by iText Software. For more information, see http://itextpdf.com/maven-update-problem-with-itext-4.2.2. As far as I know, Jasper Reports works with iText `2.1.7`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579401/which-version-of-itext-to-use-so-that-both-jasperreports-and-grails-rendering-pl

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, Both these answers say to use itext-2.7.1 which I have tried and that works but I have to use itextpdf-5.5.6 or higher. I need some mechanism so that these higher version of itext jar can do the job not the older ones.

Comment: I think you mean `2.1.7` because `2.7.1` does not exist. To make Jasper Reports work with iText `5.x.x`, you would need to modify the source of Jasper Reports, and recompile Jasper Reports. And you'd have to make sure that all relevant licenses are compatible. Have you asked on the Jasper Reports support forum? http://community.jaspersoft.com/answers?search_api_views_fulltext=itext